# Recommendation for simple Relay model?

Tags: ngspice

As I am trying to create a relay model in ngspice, I thought of a subcircuit with one inductor and two current switches with a common port, like this:

```
.SUBCKT RELAY coila coilb common no nc L_coil=5mH            
LRelay    coila coilb L_coil 
S1Relay  common no coila coilb relaySwitchOn
S2Relay  common nc coila coilb relaySwitchOff
.model relaySwitchOn  CSW it=1m ih=0.2m ron=1n roff=10g
.model relaySwitchOff CSW it=1m ih=0.2m ron=10g roff=1n            
.ends
```

as I thought to have two current based switches, that both depends on current in the inductor, but each one uses a different model so that if first switch is on, the other if off, and if first is off, the other is on, by using different `ron`, `roff` values for each switch model.

is this a good approach?

also, I tried to read the manual for inductor, and I’ve used `CSW` model type as above, but I got this error:

```
["Error on line 0 :"]
["  s.x1.s1relay 4 7 6 1 x1:relayswitchon "]
["incorrect model type"]
["Error on line 0 :"]
["  s.x1.s2relay 4 8 6 1 x1:relayswitchoff "]
["incorrect model type"]
```

thanks for any info in the right direction

**EDIT2**

Here is the relay in action that I am trying to implement:

[image]

Comment: The error can be solved reading the manual (as mentioned earlier): section 3.2.14, first line...

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I read the manual, I get `incorrect model type` while I use the type mentioned in the manual `CSW `

Comment: I would **not** use (only) an inductor to model the relay's coil. If you do, what happens to the current when a certain DC voltage is applied to the coil? What will the final value of the current be? That's why I would at least also add a series resistor. To for example model a coil for 12 V, 50 mA I would use 12V/50mA = 240 ohms. For many cases using **only** a resistor to model the relay's coil will suffice as well.

Comment: All Relays are a miniature   linear motor with back EMF at peak velocity reducing current slightly until end-stop and a series R that limits current;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error "incorrect model type" is generated when the circuit element doesn't match the corresponding description in the `.model` statement.
E.g. in

```
M1 Nd Ng Ns 0 MyMOSFET         # M -> circuit element is mosfet
model MyMOSFET NPN(Bf=75)      # NPN -> model description of a NPN =/= mosfet
```

In OP's case, the manual states:

> Two types of switches are available: a voltage controlled switch (type **S** XXXXXX, model **SW**) and a current controlled switch (type **W** XXXXXXX, model **CSW**).

The error is due using a S type element, while specifying a CSW model.

**EDIT**
From the manual:

> For the current
>   controlled switch, the controlling current is that **through the specified voltage source**. The direction of positive controlling current flow is from the positive node, through the source, to the negative node.

So, put a **voltage source in series** with the inductor and name the source e.g. Vcoilcurrent.

```
.SUBCKT RELAY coila coilb common no nc L_coil=5mH            
* insert node coilc between coila and coilb
* and connect the inductor to coilc
LRelay    coila coilc L_coil

* and a 0V DC voltage source in series between coilb and coilc
Vcoilcurrent coilc coilb dc 0

* current controlled switches starts with a capital W
W1Relay common no Vcoilcurrent relaySwitchOn
W2Relay common nc Vcoilcurrent relaySwitchOff

* current controlled switches have a corresponding switch model: CSW
* do not use extreme values like 1n and 10G for the reasons given in chapter 3.2.15 Switch Model (SW/CSW) of manual
.model relaySwitchOn  CSW it=1m ih=0.2m ron=100     roff=100 Meg
.model relaySwitchOff CSW it=1m ih=0.2m ron=100 Meg roff=100            
.ends
```

---

Regarding the modelling of a relay:
I would use the parameters you normally find in the datasheet of a relay and implement those, so:

- the coil resistance
- the must operate voltage (minimum required voltage to turn on the relay)
- the must release voltage (maximum voltage that will turn off the relay **for sure**)
- maybe a fixed coil inductance (as it is most times not specified) of 10 - 100 mH to remind users to use a freewheel diode

Comment: Thanks your answer but please bear with me, I don’t understand how would I let the current controlled switch be dependent on current between two ports? as in document, switch of type `W` has no `NC+ NC-` but I need to make switches sensitive to current at coil resistance, can this be achieved? As in your answer, you proposed voltage controlled switches, but then which two ports to use as voltage source for the switch?

Comment: @simo please find updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Huisman, I am getting more familiar with documentation thanks to your answer :)

Comment: As for threshold current of current controlled switch, is there a way to let NGSpice treat it as absolute value? thus neglecting being minus sign, as I am using it for the relay which will work on both signs positive and negative current

Comment: @Simo. Not that I know off. I think you have to add a current controlled switch in parallel to each switch which detects the negative current (e.g. rename "W1Relay" to "W1RelayPos" and add "W1RelayNeg" in parallel and add a corresponding ```.model .model relaySwitchOnNeg  CSW it=-1m ih=0.2m ron=100     roff=100 Meg```

Comment: Another way is to use a diode bridge with ideal diodes which makes the current always go the right way through the sensing voltage source (Vcoilcurrent in my answer)

Comment: I think that if NGSpice allow absolute value option for current controlled switch by adding a flag option, that would be very useful, adding four diodes would make it complicated, and the first suggestion we would need the threshold to be less than zero, as it will detect negative current, I don’t know if ngspice support reversed threshold? that works by comparing less than instead of greater than..

Comment: @simo Another option would be an Arbitrary Behavioral Current Source using abs(x): ```Bnnn n123 n124 I=abs( I(L_coil) )``` where the voltage source Vcoilcurrent is connected to nodes n123 and n124.

Comment: Oh, I have to check that option and dig into docs, thanks!

Comment: I tried to connect another `Vcoilcurrent2` in series with `Vcoilcurrent  coilc xx dc 0`  then I did `Bnnn coilc xx I= -1 * I(Vcoilcurrent2)` just for testing, shouldn’t  current at `Vcoilcurrent` be the current of `Vcoilcurrent2` multiplied by -1 as for my test?

Comment: @simo You should disconnect Vcoilcurrent from nodes coilc and xx. (So, delete line ```Vcoilcurrent coilc xx dc 0 ```). Connect ```Lrelay coila coilb L_coil``` as you did in your original question and delete node ```coilc```.  For the ```Bnnn ``` source you need to create **new** nodes, do not use nodes that have been used elsewhere. Connect Vcoilcurrent to these new nodes.

Comment: But you suggested `Bnnn` is using `I` of `L_coil`, will this be valid to get current of relay? While `L_coil` is Henry value

Comment: Ah...brainfart. It should of course be ```Bnnn newnode1 newnode2 I=abs( I(Lrelay) )```

Comment: It seems NGSpice can't recognize `Lrelay` as controlling source, as I got `Fatal error: b.x1.bnnn: unknown controlling source l.x1.lrelay \n doAnalyses: no such parameter on this device` although its there as `LRelay coila coilb L_coil `

Comment: Any idea? could it be that I am the first person who try relay on NGSpice?! :)

Comment: If you put your complete code on pastebin.com and share the link, I will have a look (my response may take a while)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that

Comment: Hi, here is my attempt to relay circuit, https://pastebin.com/YyykjTp7
you can also see the graphics of that circuit at the edit2 above, thank you M time, your help will really makes a big difference here..